# Why function SUMIFS is better than iterate (for)

Tags: excel, vba, optimization

Excel SUMIFS function can't execute if the other workbooks is closed. So, i did a SUMIFS function that opens my workbook, iterate via 'for' loop and verify if the value column needs to be added in my total variable.

I did another function that removes my 'for' loop and uses "WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(...)". My new function ran fastest than the old one.

What is the magic behind excel functions and VBA iteration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff726673.aspx#xlUsingFuncts

(emphasis added)

> User-Defined Functions
>
> User-defined functions that are programmed in C or C++ and that use
>   the C API (XLL add-in functions) generally perform faster than
>   user-defined functions that are developed using VBA or Automation (XLA
>   or Automation add-ins). For more information, see Developing Excel
>   2010 XLLs.
>
> XLM functions can also be fast, because they use the same tightly
>   coupled API as C XLL add-in functions. The performance of VBA
>   user-defined functions is sensitive to how you program and call them.
>
> Faster VBA User-Defined Functions
>
> **It is usually faster to use the Excel formula calculations and
>   worksheet functions than to use VBA user-defined functions. This is
>   because there is a small overhead for each user-defined function call
>   and significant overhead transferring information from Excel to the
>   user-defined function.** But well-designed and called user-defined
>   functions can be much faster than complex array formulas.

Answer (score 0):

One way to get more insight is to test how the performance ratio changes with different input sizes.  For example if the performance ratio remains about the same when input size increases 100-fold, than it is probably due to VBA abstraction overhead.